# How to calculate support costs / required number of staff?

Tags: untagged

I have to calculate the required number of staff (-> support costs) for using and managing a specific software system which is an on-premise solution and can manage devices like mobile devices, notebooks etc. and deploy internal enterprise applications.

I know that there are a lot of parameters like amount of users who will use the system and need support, how many software updates per year, support time (24/7) etc.
But I want to know how can this be calculated in general? Are there any best practices or methods which I can base me on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: I do not have to plan hardware costs or development costs, only the support costs which will be caused by using a software system. We have x devices and y applications which should be managed which will be used by z users. So I think I will create an excel sheet and do some calculations.

Comment: @Tim Planning staff costs is way out of scope for Server Fault -- As it's phrased it's also way too broad: we have no way of knowing what kind of maintenance will be required by this software/system (buggy systems will chew up more resources), nor what kind of users you'll have (high-maintenance users who call every day for hand-holding obviously require more support staff). The best resource I could point you at would be a [course in project management](http://www.pmi.org/).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no general approach and there can't be as this all so completely dependent on your situation that any attempt to generalize this would be meaningless.

Comment: Okay, I thought that maybe there are some approaches which I can use as a basis rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Cost estimation for software engineering exists like COCOMO and function point analysis, so I thought there is maybe sth. similiar for support costs estimations.